# equivalent in JS of the resize css applied to an SVG element

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I recently discover the CSS resize:
`

```
div {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

`
There is also a polyFill, but none of them  won't work for a SVG element :/

Is it possible at least ?

Comment: You can wrap the SVG in a div, and set the SVG to `width: 100%; height: 100%` I guess.

Comment: Thank you, but I know it, but for this question, I wish to did not have a div container. And later add to this JS code some other special functions for the drawing SVG that will interact with the resize

Comment: If your expectation is that points will change coordinates with the resize, you'll definitely need to roll your own code.

Comment: Yes, it means changing the viewbox, and other things with animations, but I just want a small code base to get started well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your code and @ChrisG's comment, you might do the following.

When one clicks on `svg`, wrap this `svg` into a resizable `div` and set the `svg` width and height attributes to '100%' so the `svg` would get the wrapper's size.
Then, when one resizes the `div`, the `svg` would be resized as well.
When one clicks out of the `div`, set the `svg` width and height attributes explicitly and remove the `div`.

See the snippet below:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    var r = document.getElementById('r');
    if (r && r != e.target) {
      var svg = r.querySelector('svg');
      svg.setAttribute('width', r.offsetWidth + 'px');
      svg.setAttribute('height', r.offsetHeight + 'px');
      r.replaceWith(svg);
    }

    var svg = e.target;
    while (!!svg && svg.nodeName != 'svg')
      svg = svg.parentElement;
    if (!svg) return;

    var r = document.createElement('div');
    r.id = 'r';
    r.style.width = svg.width.baseVal.valueAsString;
    r.style.height = svg.height.baseVal.valueAsString;
    svg.setAttribute('width', '100%');
    svg.setAttribute('height', '100%');
    svg.parentElement.insertBefore(r, svg);
    r.appendChild(svg.parentElement.removeChild(svg));

  });
});
```

```css
svg {
  background: #cef
}

#r {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 1px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle stroke="navy" stroke-width="5" fill="pink" cx="50" cy="50" r="40"/>
</svg>

<svg width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle stroke="green" stroke-width="5" fill="gold" cx="50" cy="50" r="40"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I did not expect a solution so quickly, nor through that. Surprised and admiring, because I find it rather cunning. thank you !

Comment: @MrJ, happy to help!